# Force update Diagnostic Configuration file under wad-control-container for Azure

Tags: azure, configuration-files, azure-diagnostics

I would like to update the Diagnostic configuration file for the azure roles whenever I upgrade my deployment. How can I do this automatically?

From time to time, we do change our diagnostic (using code) - and upgrade the service. But whenever we upgrade the service, it is still using the old diagnostic configuration and we do not see any new logs we have configured using new code.

How can I achieve this so that whenever I upgrade my deployment, it upgrades the diagnostic configuration as well.

Comment: Same problem here. So which solution do you adopt to conquer this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you have a bug in your diagnostics updating code.  If each role ran code in OnStart or Run to configure diagnostics on startup, there would be no reason that your instances wouldn't be properly configured.  I tend to think that imperative code that configures diagnostics is inherently a bad idea in the long run, but it should still work.  If you share the code, maybe I can spot an issue.

The best** way I have found to update and enforce configuration is to use the [diagnostics.wadcfg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411551.aspx) file and update it.  When you upgrade your deployment, it will use those settings if you have not overridden it in code somewhere.  Contrary to Microsoft's guidance at that link, it should be the preferred method as opposed to code which must be maintained and is orthogonal to your application's purpose.  Said another way - a declarative configuration file that your ops team can maintain over writing code is usually a better idea.  To use this, just include it in your deployment as content and delete any existing files in wad-control-container (and remove any code that configured diagnostics).  It will just configure itself from that file then when you next upgrade.

** you can also using a 3rd party SaaS monitoring to set and maintain your diagnostics config.  I work on one such one, but I am guessing you want to know how to do it yourself.  :)

Comment: Actually, the settings configured through imperative codes are taking the first superiority, so why such a situation which disobeys the precedence would happen? Is it a bug of Windows Azure Diagnostics?

Comment: Yes.  Code takes first precedence - that's what I said.  The diagnostics.wadconfig file is used if you a.) don't code imperatively, or b.) it does not find a previous config out in blob storage.

Comment: Now, I code imperatively, so the diagnostics.wadconfig file won't be used. It's disappointed that the code haven't any effects, like the author of this question said. Do you know why?

Comment: Impossible for me to tell you without seeing code (open a different question).  I can state definitively that if you code it correctly, it most certainly will persist.  Once that happens, only a remote configuration after the fact will change the settings.